# Are the X86 'cmpps' instruction and the LLVM IR 'fcmp' instruction interchangeable?

Tags: x86, llvm, sse

Does every LLVM IR 'fcmp' instruction have a compatible X86 cmpps instruction?
And what about vice-versa? Can every X86 cmpps instruction (say with only register operands) be described with a single LLVM 'fcmp' instruction?
A tricky part of the question is how are NaN's, Inf's, -0.0 and other corner cases handled by each language.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer since I don't know much about LLVM IR, but this is too long for a comment.

> Does every LLVM IR 'fcmp' instruction have a compatible X86 cmpps instruction?

Definitely not exactly; if there is high garbage in the upper elements of the vectors, you could raise an Invalid or Denormal exception in the MXCSR status bits where the C abstract machine would not have done so.

But with CMPSS for scalar operands, you can probably do everything.   If you're doing a scalar compare, it's often better to use [UCOMISS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UCOMISS.html) to set flags instead of using a CMPSS to generate a 0 or -1 in the destination XMM register.

The best documentation for x86 XMM CMPp/s instructions is found under the [CMPPD entry](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/CMPPD.html) (which is alphabetically first; the others refer to its tables).  That HTML extract isn't perfect, consult Intel's PDF for better-formatted tables.  (links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

---

If you need to avoid raising an exception when comparing operands that may be NaN, you may not be able to use CMPSS without AVX, at least not efficiently.  The SSE version only allows the first 8 predicates (imm8= 0..7), and many of them are of the S (Signalling) variety, that is they raise `#IA` if either operand is a QNAN.  AVX adds Q (Quiet) versions of all predicates that don't signal, like [UCOMISS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UCOMISS.html).

---

And of course, if you're targeting a 32-bit CPU and can't assume SSE support, you need to use x87.  (FCOMI, or if you can't even assume P6 or newer, FCOM).